# Are all rebel droids programmed so that they can kill imperials?

Tags: star-wars

In a recent canon comic we see R2-D2 killing imperials. What I'm wondering is that in the past it was established that droids aside from combat droids were not allowed to harm someone.

So I'm wondering: Are all rebel droids programmed so that they can kill imperials? Thus even protocol droids...?

Comment: Where did you get that 'droids aside from combat droids were not allowed to harm someone'?  In current canon and legends canon we see agressive droids, like K2-SO, the nanny droid in legends that watched over Han and Leia's kids, 'Goldie' from Clone Wars, even R2 in Revenge of the Sith wrecked things (albeit other droids)

Comment: @CBredlow aside from combat droids and reprogrammed spy droids, torture droids (and chopper) I never saw any droids in any of the films or series using lethal force on a non droid living intelligent being. Thus it seemed to me that they have a rule imprinted there. (droids vs. droids don't count there though)

Comment: You are asking a question based on a flawed premise that you anecdotally assume. It would be better to ask if you assumption is correct. Or prove that it is correct in the question, before asking something that requires said assumption to be factual.

Comment: @amflare In *Solo Command*, Squeaky the protocol droid is severely put out by inadvertently killing (he jettisoned a part of his ship that he wasn't told was a bomb). His exact words were "I've caused damage to other beings! I'm not sure I can cope." On the one hand, this suggests he had some kind of ethical imperative not to hurt people; on the other hand, it doesn't prove that he *couldn't* if the need arose, only that it would be undesirable.

Comment: @Cadence What does that have to do with anything? The question is still based on a flawed premise that OP is anecdotally assuming.

Comment: I've never seen any lawyers kill any people either, but that doesn't mean that they *can't*

Answer (score -1):

For droids that were specifically designed to kill humans, it's obvious that they can. However, R2-D2 had presumably never had his memory erased (causing the frantic search for him after the Battle of Bothuwai), which caused him to develop his own personality. Since he was heavily modified by the Naboo authorities, it is also possible that his programming was modified to allow him to protect his allies, even if that required the killing of sentients. I believe that these are the same reasons for chopper. However, all of this is merely speculation.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While we appreciate this answer we are a Q/A site and mere speculation, even if informed, is usually frowned upon. Can you add any sources to back up your answer, even if it's for the R2D2 didn't have his memory erased part.

Comment: Thank-you for your advice.

Comment: When did Naboo modify R2?